# How to solve the logistic regression model prediction error?

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

Given a data set of 13389 data records with "win" (binary) as the target variable, a logistic regression model with confusion matrix is built, but it comes out (1) only 4017 records are predicted (0,0) and (1,1) but no records in (0,1) and (1,0), and also (2) ValueError: y_true takes value in {'0', '1'} and pos_label is not specified: either make y_true take value in {0, 1} or {-1, 1} or pass pos_label explicitly.  Appreciate for professional advice.  Many thanks!

`print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))`[Dataset info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrcGH.png)
`print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))`[Confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxioD.png)
[ValueError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y04a1.png)

[No (0,1) and (1,0) predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LnjP.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: X=df6.drop(['all_or_nothing'], axis=1).values
y=df6['win'].values
logmodel = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))
predictions = logmodel.predict(X_test)
probs = logmodel.predict_proba(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not sure how you defined your y_test. But could you check this page for your confusion matrix? Your results shows that all of your predictions are true. However it should be better of using it with your y_true and y_pred as like here..
   https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html
2. You should change your y_true as indicated to number format from string format. Check your y_true definition. [y_true format](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html)

Comment: Thanks but how can i change the y_true format from string to number?

Comment: It comes out to be: TypeError: Labels in y_true and y_pred should be of the same type. Got y_true=[0 1] and y_pred=['0' '1']. Make sure that the predictions provided by the classifier coincides with the true labels.  Very puzzled about the y_pred format approach?  Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: What is the results of y=df6['win'].values, I mean .. print(y)

Comment: You didnt provide the what is y and x. for example, You can change like that -->  y = [int(y) for i in y]